# Spring bean is null

Tags: hibernate, spring, tapestry

I'm working on a tapestry,spring,hibernate web-app with jetty 6.1.26 as web-server,and I can't get rid of the nullpointexception for the userDao bean(which is defined in application_context_dao.xml::

```
public class UserManagerImpl implements UserManager {

    private UserDao userDao;

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public boolean checkLogin (String login, String password) {

        return userDao.checkLogin(login, password);

    }
```

application_context_dao.xml:

```
<beans>

<bean id="userDao" class="org.prikic.projektni.domain.dao.hibernate3.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- sessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionProxy" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="insert*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, readOnly</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
<display-name>projektni Tapestry 5 Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <!-- The only significant configuration for Tapestry 5, this informs Tapestry 
        of where to look for pages, components and mixins. -->
    <param-name>tapestry.app-package</param-name>
    <param-value>org.prikic.projektni</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Specify some additional Modules for two different execution modes: 
    development and qa. Remember that the default execution mode is production -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>tapestry.development-modules</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.prikic.projektni.services.DevelopmentModule
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>tapestry.qa-modules</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.prikic.projektni.services.QaModule
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/application_context_dao.xml
        /WEB-INF/application_context.xml
         <!-- classpath:application_context*.xml --> 
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>app</filter-name>
    <!-- Special filter that adds in a T5 IoC module derived from the Spring 
        WebApplicationContext. -->
    <filter-class>org.apache.tapestry5.spring.TapestrySpringFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>app</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Any help would be appreciated...

I apologize for not putting the other spring app context xml file,here it is:

application_context.xml:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="userManagerTarget" class="org.prikic.projektni.services.impl.UserManagerImpl">
            <property name="userDao">
                    <ref bean="userDao" />
            </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="userManager" parent="transactionProxy">               
            <property name="target">
                    <ref bean="userManagerTarget"/>
            </property>
            <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource"/>
            </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Index.java:

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Persist;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.SessionState;
import org.apache.tapestry5.beaneditor.Validate;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import org.prikic.projektni.services.UserManager;

public class Index {

private static final String BAD_CREDENTIALS = "Bad login and/or password. Please retry.";


//private boolean error = false;
@Persist
private boolean error;

@SessionState(create=false)
private String login;

@Inject
@Service("userManager")
private UserManager userManager;

private String password;

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

@Validate("required")
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    String ret = null;
    if (error) {
        ret = BAD_CREDENTIALS;
    }
    return ret;
}

@Validate("required")
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

String onSuccess() {

    String ret = "Index";
    error = true;

    boolean s = userManager.checkLogin(login, password);

    if (s) {
        error = false;
        ret = "Home";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the UserManagerImpl bean defined? How do you get an instance of UserManagerImpl?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's missing in your configuration snippet, I assume it is absent altogether:

```
<bean id="userManagerImpl" class="org.prikic.projektni.domain.dao.hibernate3.UserManagerImpl">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</bean>
```

After adding this bean to your Spring configuration, it should work. Of course now you cannot just call:

```
new UserManagerImpl();
```

Because Spring knows nothing about this class thus cannot perform dependency injection. I don't know Tapestry, but looks like you are already using [`TapestrySpringFilter`](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/spring/TapestrySpringFilter.html) that seems to somehow itnegrate Tapestry with Spring. The JavaDoc says it is:

> exposing each bean in it as a Tapestry IoC service

If you use this so-called IoC service and somehow obtain `UserManager` instance, you'll be fine.

Comment: @Borislav: please edit your question rather than posting here. If you **do** declare `userManagerImpl` in XML, how do you obtain it? This is crucial.